# How to launch activity and show specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity that has several fragments which are added and then shown/hidden. This is because the MainActivity uses a `NavigationDrawer`. Clicking on items in the drawer causes different fragments to be added (if they do not exist), or shown/hidden if they do.

My question is, how can I launch my MainActivity via an intent from a different activity, and at the same time show a specific fragment?

Would I have to pass some extra to my MainActivity and then based on that data, add/show/hide the relevant fragment? Is there another way?

Comment: yes, you'd need to pass an extra intent to the activity and do some work based on the value of that

Comment: Actually you will be in main activity, as in launch activity within which you will load/ switch different fragments into your `FrameLayout` based on selection in navigation drawer items. You can reference anything from your activity using `getActivity()`.

Comment: You can do it like the way mentioned in the post below https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750201/3380537

Answer (score 21):

When you create your Intent, you can give it an extra that determines the fragment to load.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityClass.class);
i.putExtra("frgToLoad", FRAGMENT_A);

// Now start your activity
startActivity(i);
```

Now, inside your activity check the extra and load the right Fragment:

```
OnCreate(){
    ...

    int intentFragment = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("frgToLoad");

    switch (intentFragment){
        case FRAGMENT_A:
            // Load corresponding fragment
            break;
        case FRAGMENT_B:
            // Load corresponding fragment
            break;
        case FRAGMENT_C:
            // Load corresponding fragment
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check if `getIntent.getExtras().getInt()` is null or not before you you try to assign a value to intentFragment. This is because that line of code is called whether you are coming from `ActivityClass` or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use sharedPreference to achieve the goals. Save the index after you open you TAB/Fragment.

```
        //get current tab
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String position = sharedPreferences.getString("tab_opened", null);
        if(position==null){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,true);
        }else if(position=="0"){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0,true);
        }else if(position=="1"){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,true);
        }else if(position=="2"){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2,true);
        }

}// <<<~~~ THAT IS END OF onCreate() method.
```

Please refer to this tutorial : [OPEN THIS](http://www.androidbie.com/2017/01/android-sliding-tab-how-to-open.html) .

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin,

```
val i = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
i.putExtra("fragmentToLoad", "fragment2")
startActivity(i)
```

Inside your activity check the extra and load the intended Fragment:

```
val intentFragment = intent?.extras?.getString("fragmentToLoad")
when (intentFragment) {
    "fragment2" -> {
        val fragment = Fragment2()

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

[android navigation-migrate](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for something like this, hope so!

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {    
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(MCConstants.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
    clearAllBackStack();
    FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new FirstFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment,
                "FTAG").commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new SecFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment,
                "STAG").commit();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new ThirdFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment,
                "TTAG").commit();
        break;
    }
}
```