# how to make a fragment as a app launching activity

Tags: java, android

I have "home_fragment.java" class file in my project 
which i need to be launched when the app starts.
but i am only able to add 'activities' as launch default,not fragments.
please help me to add a 'fragment' as a launch activity.
i am new to android ,thank you.

this is my  **home_fragment.java**

```
public class home_fragment extends Fragment {
    View myView;
    Button more;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout,container, false);
        Button button = (Button) myview.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something
            }
        });
        return myview;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't use fragment as launching activity because fragment is not activity, it's just similar to it or we can say that it can be small part of activity. you can take one activity and set your fragment to it for complete your desired work.

Comment: probable duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063704/how-to-launch-activity-and-show-specific-fragment

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the fragment into the activity and launch this activity.

it is not possible for fragment to be launched independently.

in empty activity add this xml

```
<fragment android:name="com.company.appName.fragments.FirstFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and in activity onCreate method do this

```
Fragment fr = new FirstFragment();
fr.setArguments(args);
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: sir please describe how to add fragment to an activity ,mine is a navigation drawer app.

Comment: do you need any further explanation?

Comment: @BenSahil If your question is "how to add fragment to an activity" here is your answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159982/how-do-i-add-a-fragment-to-an-activity-with-a-programmatically-created-content-v

Comment: comment out this line fr.setArguments(args);
 if you want to pass any data to fragment from activity them you pass it using setArgumetns method. in your case comment it out.

Comment: fr.setArguments(args);

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` must be launched from `Activity`. 
You can do it by launching your fragment from your activity `onCreate()` method like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyFragment()).commit();
    }
```