# Restarting Activity on Specific Fragment, when Using a Separate FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

**Background**
I have an android app using fragments. I'm using a separate FragmentPagerAdapter (i.e. as a separate class, outside MainActivity).

*MainActivity.java*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}
```

*SectionsPagerAdapter.java*

```
public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new frag1();
        case 1:
            return new frag2();
        case 2:
            return new frag3();
        case 3:
            return new frag4();
        case 4:
            return new frag5();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Name1";
        case 1:
            return "Name2";
        case 2:
            return "Name3";
        case 3:
            return "Name4";
        case 4:
            return "Name5";
    }
    return null;
}
```

**The Issue**

I need to refresh the view of, say, fragment #3 from fragment#2 (the ultimate goal is for changes the user initiates on fragment #2 to be visible as soon as the user proceeds to fragment#3. I have tried to detach/attach fragment #3 itself as soon as it is visible, like this:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
```

Unfortunately, a) this has a penalty in performance, as there is a "stutter" during navigation; b) it doesn't work reliably. Some things (the texts of some buttons) are not refreshed, for some reason I can't figure out.

In any case, I have discovered that the only 100% reliable method for forcing a refresh/redraw is to restart the activity (for example through an onClickListener on a Save button the user needs to press on the previous fragment, #2). But this restarts the Activity on fragment #1

**My Question**
How can I restart the activity on this specific fragment (#3), considering the fact I'm using a separate FragmentPagerAdapter?

I've studied several other questions/answers, for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064344

but how can I implement something like this (putting extras on the intent call) when the FragmentPagerAdapter is on a separate class? Alternatively, is there something else I can do to refresh the fragment view?

If you need extra info or code, let me know and I'd be glad to add clarification.
**EDIT:**
I managed to find another solution that so far seems to be working as intended. I added the following code on the onClickListener of the Save button on fragment #2

```
    frag3 f3 = new frag3();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, f3);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
```

However, I'm *still* interested in my original question (how to start an activity on a specific fragment when using a separate FragmentPagerAdapter), so if you have any ideas about that, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, wasn't that simple...
`this.recreate();` not only restarts the activity but it also *remembers* the fragment position.
Just in case someone else needs this, when you're working from fragments you need to use it this way:

- First declare the activity which contains the fragment in question. E.g.

  ```
  public class frag1 extends Fragment {
  ...
  Activity mactivity;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity MainActivity) {
      super.onAttach(MainActivity);
      mactivity = MainActivity; 
  }
  ```
- Then instead of `getActivity().recreate();` simply use `mactivity.recreate();`