# how to switch between fragments of two different activity class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two different activities, A & B. 
Both have `NavigationDrawer` , look alike, but not are the same, because I could not get the drawer layout ID of activity A in activity B.

Both activity has 3 fragments each (total 6).

The `NavigationDrawer` contains all fragments of activity class A only. My problem is, when I am in activity  B, and try to open one fragment of activity A from navigation drawer, it throws an error

```
No view found for id 0x7f090047 (com.wlodsgn.bunbunup:id/linear) for fragment FmMenu{b1e537f0 #0 id=0x7f090047}
```

How do I achieve it?

Comment: You can show and hide menu items in navigation drawer. Why is it necessary to have two different menus, drawers and activities?

Comment: The layout for activity A has action bar and layout of activity B does not have action bar. (theme Theme.AppCompat.DarkActionBar & Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar). the drawer button in activity A is in action bar and in activity B, the drawer button is inside a search bar (layout A does not have a search bar).

Answer (score 0):

I have created an intent inside the second activity and started the activity A with information about the fragment to be called.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityClass.class);
i.putExtra("frgToLoad", "FRAGMENT_A");
startActivity(i);
```

Now, inside activity A, checked the extra and load the right Fragment:

```
OnCreate(){
...
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
String intentFragment = getIntent().getExtras().getString("frgToLoad");

switch (intentFragment){
    case "FRAGMENT_A":
        // Load corresponding fragment
        break;
    case "FRAGMENT_B":
        // Load corresponding fragment
        break;
    case "FRAGMENT_C":
        // Load corresponding fragment
        break;
   }
}
}
```

One have to check if intent is null or not before I try to assign a value to intentFragment. This is because that line of code is called whether I am coming from activity B or not, and it will throw error if intent is null.

credit : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064344/3380537